# Consume Stream from WCF as fast as possible

Tags: c#, wcf

**The setup:**

`App A` runs a rendering of 3D models

`App B` generates models and sends them (plain text OBJ format) to `App A` via WCF's streaming operation

```cs
[OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
void VisualizeModel(Stream model);
```

I send models through localhost, so bandwidth should be big enough to send pretty huge models, but a rendering library I use has a slow method for reading them from a stream.

**The problem**

I need to prevent `App B` from waiting for a long time until `App A` consumes it completely (it takes up to 10 sec). So I try to copy the input stream into an intermediate stream

```cs
modelDrain = new MemoryStream(1024*1024*300);
model.CopyTo(modelDrain);
modelDrain.Position = 0;
```

then I start a `Task` to run rendering asynchronously, but **I don't `await` for this `Task`** - this way the WCF operation finishes practically as soon as I make the copy. It takes about 4 sec to finish the WCF operation this way. But the thing is that I *generate* these models in *2 sec*, so I doubt that constructing the 3D model is twice as light than just copying it over HTTP.

**The questions**

Can I consume a WCF stream any other way (maybe via another `Stream` class) to speed the thing up?

Is HTTP over localhost that slow? (like 4 seconds to send about 100 Mb of text, while generating of such data takes only 2 seconds)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WCF, you can increase the transmission rate through compression encoder.The following will compare the effect of using compression encoder with that of not using compression encoder.

```
    public Stream Echo()
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(1000, 40000);
        for (int i = 0; i < bitmap.Width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < bitmap.Height; j++)
            {
                bitmap.SetPixel(i, j, (Math.Abs(i - j) < 2) ? Color.Blue : Color.Yellow);
            }
        }
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        bitmap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);


        return ms;


    }
```

This is the stream to be transmitted.

```
     static void Main()
    {
        DateTime afterDT = System.DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine(afterDT);
        SampleServerClient client = new SampleServerClient();
        client.Echo();
        afterDT = System.DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine(afterDT);
        Console.WriteLine("OK");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

This is the code of the client-side. I will record the time required for the client-side to receive the stream.

[image]

This is the time spent without using the compression encoder.

[image]

This is the time spent using compression encoder.

Due to the low efficiency of gzip image compression, the transmission performance has not been greatly improved, but if other large files, the performance will be improved a lot.

The following link is about how to use compression encoder in WCF:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/custom-message-encoder-compression-encoder

Comment: I'll mark this as answer, though I didn't manage to implement compression for my service and test it out.